# How to sync the indices of two arrays based on a shared value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Given two arrays of the same length and identical content, how can one sort an array to be the in same order as the second array, based on a shared property?

Example:

```
let array1 = [{id: 123, ...}, {id: 456, ...}, {id: 789, ...}] // order always stays the same
let array2 = [{id: 456, ...}, {id: 789, ...}, {id: 123, ...}] // order is always different
```

How can I sort array1 such that:

`array1[0].id` is 456 and
`array2[0].id` is 456

Comment: What do you mean by sync? Also share the expected output and code which you have tried.

Comment: @HassanImam by "sync" I mean make indices of the arrays identical

Comment: Why not `array1[0].id` and `array2[0].id` to be 123 ?

Comment: @HassanImam Note I said `array2` will always be different. I want the order of `array1` to match that of `array2`. Thus, 456 is this example.

Comment: Maybe you need something like this `array1.sort((a,b) => array2.findIndex(o => o.id === a.id) - array2.findIndex(o => o.id === b.id))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the first and push to the second by index:

```js
let arr1 = [{id: 123}, {id: 456}, {id: 789}] // order always stays the same
let arr2 = [{id: 456}, {id: 789}, {id: 123}] 

arr1.forEach((obj1, idx) => {
  arr2[idx] = obj1
})

console.log(arr1, arr2)
```

Comment: @jmedran glad I could help!

Comment: Marking this accepted. I found this answer to be the simplest of the three - just what I required. Not sure why the question was closed and labeled "unfocused". The question clearly inspired thought and diversity thereof, demonstrated by the different solutions.

Comment: You should be aware that this leaves you with references to the objects in `arr1` in `arr2` so mutating objects in the latter will also change the former (maybe useful? maybe not.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming array2 has the objects we care about and array1 specifies the order, map over the ordering array using it to select the objects to be ordered...

```js
let array1 = [{id: 123 }, {id: 456 }, {id: 789, }]
let array2 = [{id: 456, name: '456' }, {id: 789, name: '789' }, {id: 123, name: '123' }]

let array2ElementsSortedByArray1 = array1.map(e => {
  return array2.find(e2 => e2.id === e.id)
})

console.log(array2ElementsSortedByArray1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a hash of the shape `{id: index, ...}` from `array2` and then use this to order the elements of `array1`. This saves you the cost of `find()` on each iteration.

```js
let array1 = [{ id: 123, }, { id: 456, }, { id: 789, }] // order always stays the same
let array2 = [{ id: 456, }, { id: 789, }, { id: 123, }]

const
  indeces = Object.fromEntries(array2.map(({ id }, i) => [id, i])), // { 456: 0, 789: 1, 123: 2 }
  ordered = [];
array1.forEach(o => ordered[indeces[o.id]] = { ...o });

console.log(ordered)
```